# Serial throughput using AltSoftSerial on Arduino

Tags: rs232

My project involves a commercially available device that can be remotely controlled by a computer over RS232. I'd like to put an Arduino Pro Mini, which has a second serial port provided by the AltSoftSerial Library, between the device and the computer. One of the Arduino's serial ports will connect to the device under control, and the other will connect to the computer. One function of the Arduino will be to simply read incoming data on one port and immediately write it to the other port. I'm not yet sure how heavy the serial traffic will be, although my early impression is that it will come from sporadic, user-initiated commands and resulting responses.

Assuming all baud, stop bit, data bits and parity are configured correctly, is what I'm proposing possible with the AltSoftSerial Library? Is it likely that this approach will introduce delays and/or errors that are prohibitive?

Comment: That would depend on unspecified details.  There are plenty of cheap MCUs with two hardware UARTs or a UART and USB you can use as a proxy to present another virtual one to a PC if the timing is sufficiently loose.

Comment: Did you consider Arduino mega? It has more than 1 true hardware UART which means there is no software involved in transmission and reception. Otherwise, you have to go with the best software library to simulate the second serial port. All depends on what you want to achieve which is still not clearly mentioned in the question